# How to properly disable SMAP from a linux module?

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel

I am following a tutorial from [here](http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-2-a-character-device/).

I have the following code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>           // Macros used to mark up functions e.g. __init __exit
#include <linux/module.h>         // Core header for loading LKMs into the kernel
#include <linux/device.h>         // Header to support the kernel Driver Model
#include <linux/kernel.h>         // Contains types, macros, functions for the kernel
#include <linux/fs.h>             // Header for the Linux file system support
#include <linux/uaccess.h>          // Required for the copy to user function
#define  DEVICE_NAME "ebbchar"    ///< The device will appear at /dev/ebbchar using this value
#define  CLASS_NAME  "ebb"        ///< The device class -- this is a character device driver

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");            ///< The license type -- this affects available functionality
MODULE_AUTHOR("Derek Molloy");    ///< The author -- visible when you use modinfo
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple Linux char driver for the BBB");  ///< The description -- see modinfo
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");            ///< A version number to inform users

static int    majorNumber;                  ///< Stores the device number -- determined automatically
static char   message[256] = {0};           ///< Memory for the string that is passed from userspace
static short  size_of_message;              ///< Used to remember the size of the string stored
static int    numberOpens = 0;              ///< Counts the number of times the device is opened
static struct class*  ebbcharClass  = NULL; ///< The device-driver class struct pointer
static struct device* ebbcharDevice = NULL; ///< The device-driver device struct pointer

static int     dev_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
static int     dev_release(struct inode *, struct file *);
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);

static struct file_operations fops =
{
   .open = dev_open,
   .read = dev_read,
   .write = dev_write,
   .release = dev_release,
};

static int __init ebbchar_init(void){
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Initializing the EBBChar LKM\n");

   // Try to dynamically allocate a major number for the device -- more difficult but worth it
   majorNumber = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &fops);
   if (majorNumber<0){
      printk(KERN_ALERT "EBBChar failed to register a major number\n");
      return majorNumber;
   }
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: registered correctly with major number %d\n", majorNumber);

   // Register the device class
   ebbcharClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);
   if (IS_ERR(ebbcharClass)){                // Check for error and clean up if there is
      unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);
      printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to register device class\n");
      return PTR_ERR(ebbcharClass);          // Correct way to return an error on a pointer
   }
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: device class registered correctly\n");

   // Register the device driver
   ebbcharDevice = device_create(ebbcharClass, NULL, MKDEV(majorNumber, 0), NULL, DEVICE_NAME);
   if (IS_ERR(ebbcharDevice)){               // Clean up if there is an error
      class_destroy(ebbcharClass);           // Repeated code but the alternative is goto statements
      unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);
      printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to create the device\n");
      return PTR_ERR(ebbcharDevice);
   }
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: device class created correctly\n"); // Made it! device was initialized
   return 0;
}

static void __exit ebbchar_exit(void){
   device_destroy(ebbcharClass, MKDEV(majorNumber, 0));     // remove the device
   class_unregister(ebbcharClass);                          // unregister the device class
   class_destroy(ebbcharClass);                             // remove the device class
   unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);             // unregister the major number
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Goodbye from the LKM!\n");
}

static int dev_open(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep){
   numberOpens++;
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Device has been opened %d time(s)\n", numberOpens);
   return 0;
}

static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
   int error_count = 0;
   // copy_to_user has the format ( * to, *from, size) and returns 0 on success
   error_count = copy_to_user(buffer, message, size_of_message);

   if (error_count==0){            // if true then have success
      printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Sent %d characters to the user\n", size_of_message);
      return (size_of_message=0);  // clear the position to the start and return 0
   }
   else {
      printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Failed to send %d characters to the user\n", error_count);
      return -EFAULT;              // Failed -- return a bad address message (i.e. -14)
   }
}

static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
   sprintf(message, "%s(%zu letters)", buffer, len);   // appending received string with its length
   size_of_message = strlen(message);                 // store the length of the stored message
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Received %zu characters from the user\n", len);
   return len;
}

static int dev_release(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep){
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Device successfully closed\n");
   return 0;
}

module_init(ebbchar_init);
module_exit(ebbchar_exit);
```

I have a small testing file as well from the tutorial. The problem is that when the testing code runs, the process ends up being killed. The logs files say it is due to Supervisor Mode access and that a page fault exception was thrown.

After some research and looking in log files It came down to  compatibility problems with Supervisor Mode Access Prevention, where kernel code can't access user code due to the new SMAP feature of some CPUs.

After disabling SMAP at boot time with the `nosmap` option the testing code works just fine.

I am looking for a way to disable/circumvent SMAP properly in module code. Since this application could run on multiple CPUs, I don't think that changing the CR4 register is the proper way.

I think the `copy_to_user()` function is a good lead. The problem arises when write is called. Could anyone point to me what is the proper way to code the `write()` function for this module?

Comment: How long the message you are trying to write? And where `__user` annotations are? (Hint: SMAP has nothing to do with a broken code)

Comment: Sorry I am new to module development but I think I pointed out that the testing program works with SMAP disabled. What are __user annotations? The message I am writing is short like Hello or Hello world!

Comment: *__user* annotation shows that memory address space is for user applications. When you see such memory, it means you need to use *copy_from_user()* or *copy_to_user()* helpers to access it from kernel. That's why the code above is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having a problem, disabling SMAP *won't solve it*, it will only *hide it*. The fact that SMAP kills your process is good and it should stay that way, it's a security measure of the Linux kernel and it should not be disabled only to make a buggy module work.

Your error is here:

```
sprintf(message, "%s(%zu letters)", buffer, len);
```

you are reading user space memory from kernel space, which is wrong, and SMAP prevents this generating a fault.

You should use [`copy_from_user()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/uaccess.h#L141), since you are dealing with a user space buffer:

```
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filep, const char __user *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
    unsigned long remaining;

    // NEVER copy more than your message buffer size.
    if (len > 256)
        len = 256;

    // Ensure that the additional string fits (XXX because len is at most 3 chars).
    if (len + strlen(" (XXX letters)") >= 256) {
        pr_info("User buffer is too big (%zu).\n", len);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    remaining = copy_from_user(message, buffer, len); 
    if (remaining > 0) {
        pr_info("Failed to copy %lu characters from the user.\n", remaining);
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    sprintf(message + len, " (%zu letters)", len);
    size_of_message = len + strlen(message + len);

    pr_info("Received %zu characters from the user.\n", len);
    return len;
}
```

---

A few other tips:

- `error_count` should be an `unsigned long` instead of an `int` since `copy_to_user()` returns that type.
- Your `dev_read()` and `dev_write()` functions take pointers from user space. Any time a kernel function takes a pointer that comes from user space, that pointer should be declared using the `__user` annotation, like I did in the function above.
- You can use the macro [`pr_info()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/printk.h#L309) instead of `printk(KERN_INFO ...)`, also like I did above.
- You can avoid writing the module name (`EBBChar:`) every single time at the beginning of each line simply by re-defining the `pr_fmt` macro like this:

  ```
  // This will make any pr_* function (except pr_cont) prepend the module name to each message.
  // KBUILD_MODNAME is automatically generated when building and is your module name.
  // Put this at the top of your module.

  #ifdef pr_fmt
  #undef pr_fmt
  #endif
  #define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt
  ```